# Remove extra space by line numbers in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I have no idea if this is the right community for this question, so please feel free to move it if it is not.

In Visual Studio 2015, there appear to be six character spaces for line numbers, even if your file only has 30 lines - so this allows for fewer characters of actual code on the screen.  Is there a way to remove the extra space?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are following margins left of code: breakpoints/bookmarks (17 px), line numbers (35 px), quick actions (18 px), file changes (10 px) and outlining (9 px).

[image]

I don't see any deliberately wasted space and I don't see any public options to change width of existing elements.

Comment: It's not possible to remove all of the margins, just some of them. If you turn off all margins, you're still left with ~20 pixels of waste. I think the one which is not removable is the quick actions margin (or is it?).

Comment: You can hide the breakpoint margin, the line numbers, and can get change indicators to be on the scrollbar.  There are extensions available to hide the remaining margins.  I don't know about "deliberate" but I do think an entire 18px for a lightbulb is an unnecessary margin; the icon could have been put inside another area.

Answer (score 3):

First: Tools > Options > Text Editor > C# (or whatever language you use) > General > untick "Line numbers"

Second: Tools > Options > Text Editor > General > untick "selection margin" and "indicator margin"

Answer (score 1):

If you are meaning this gutter between the line numbers and the gutter for break points, it how is used to display various code helpers (e.g. refactor indicators, lightbulbs for code improvements etc.)

If you take those indicators away you have about 2 extra character spaces.[image]

Comment: Not between the line numbers and the break points - between the line numbers and the code.  (So, to the right of the line numbers.)  This space is larger than it was in 2013.

Comment: How does one 'take those indicators away'...?

Comment: @zimdanen I think it's the quick-actions margin which takes space between line numbers and code, and I can't seem to find how to remove it. It doesn't go away even if line numbers and everything else is disabled.

Comment: Hi. How can we make that line numbers smaller in size? My line number is 4-digit until now and it is useful for me to make them smaller.