# How to reduce the size of the editor margin/gutter in VS2022?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

How to reduce the size of the editor marin/gutter (i.e. the space between line-numbers and the indicator margin):

[image: Screenshot of Visual Studio 2022]

The situation is of course rare, but maybe someone faced such a problem, if so, please tell me how to do it. A lot of space is wasted because of this.

Highlighted in red the area that I want to reduce.

There is nothing like that in the settings.

Comment: Have you seen this? (It's for VS2015, but I think it also applies to VS2022): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32614305/remove-extra-space-by-line-numbers-in-visual-studio-2015

Comment: Probably added by some VS extension you have installed.

Comment: I was able to reduce the size for myself by going to options -> Text Editor -> C# -> advanced. And unchecking "Show inheritance margin." - not sure if that will work for your language selection or not.